# UIGestureRecognizer Crash

Tags: ios, crash, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am add to put a swipe up gesture to an image, but when swiped, app craches with `BAD_EXEC` error.

This is what I have:

.h file:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeUpGesture;
    IBOutlet UIImageView*   myImage;  //Connected from Interface Builder
    IBOutlet UIScrollView*  myScrollView;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeUpGesture;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView* myImage;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView*  myScrollView;
```

.m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

   //myImage is inside of myScrollView

   swipeUpGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swiped)];
   [swipeUpGesture setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp];
   [swipeUpGesture setDelegate:self];
   [myImage addGestureRecognizer: swipeUpGesture];

}


- (void)swiped:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)sentGesture
{
    NSLog (@"swiped");
}
```

So basically, within `myView`, I have `myScrollView`.  Inside of `myScrollView`, I have `myImage`.

When I run above code, app runs until I swipe up, then it actually recognizes the swipe, but does not get to `NSLog`, crashes and I get `BAD_EXEC`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the whole error msg?

Answer (score 3):

If you use `addSubview`, do the following:

```
[self addChildViewController:myViewController];
```

After that:

```
[self.view addSubView: myViewController.view];
```

Then use a UISwipeGestureRecognizer in the view controller.

Answer (score 2):

You have a signature mismatch.

```
swipeUpGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swiped)];
```

Your selector is "swiped", without a colon, which means objective c runtime will try to find a method that takes "zero" parameter.

And since your "swiped" takes in a parameter, the runtime will fail to find a match when it tries to invoke the method and so crashes.

--

Change your @selector(swiped) to @selector(swiped:) and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a colon:

```
swipeUpGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swiped)];
```

should be

```
swipeUpGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swiped:)];
```

Without a colon, the Obj-C runtime will try to find a method without any arguments.

Comment: After fixing those, I still get the same kind of crash.  "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x8)"  http://img607.imageshack.us/img607/4936/screenshot20130514at105.png

Answer (score 0):

(As @Undo said, you forgot a colon.)

However, you can still get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error if your ViewController was released before the touch event occurred.

This can happen when adding the view of ViewController as a subview to another view controller.  e.g.

```
 [mainViewController.view addSubview:self.view]
```

Where self is your MyViewController. You can check for this by adding a breakpoint into the

```
-(void)dealloc
```

method of your MyViewController.  And checking if MyViewController is dealloced before your touch event.

You can fix this by adding a strong reference to MyViewController (ARC) wherever it is that you instantiate it.